# PHP Select with PDO Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object error

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm getting a `Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object` error in my PHP when using PDO to select data that was sent via an AJAX call.

Searching around on StackOverflow I've found many answers to this error, but none work to fix my problem.

The weird part is that the other PHP files use the same PDO calls and work successfully, but this one is giving me the non-object error only.

To note, the PDO connection is identical to the other pages where it works, so I know that's not causing the problem.

Also, I have tested that the AJAX data sent is being received, and that is working too.

PHP Code

```
$mysql_user = "NotTelling";
$mysql_password = "DefinatelyNotThis";
try
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=somehost;dbname=somename", $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $inPword = $_POST['password'];
    $lat =  $_POST['lat'];
    $lon =  $_POST['lon'];

    $loggedin = "";
    $password_hash = "";
    $loggedinstatus = "";
    $pts = "";

    function getLoginInfo()
    {
        $sth = $dbh -> prepare('SELECT pword, loggedin, points FROM login WHERE uname = :uname');
        $sth->bindParam(':uname', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            echo $row['pword'];
            echo $row['loggedin'];
            echo $row['points'];
        }
        $password_hash = $fetch['pword'];
        $loggedinstatus = $fetch['loggedin'];
        $pts = $fetch["points"];

        if($password_hash === null || $loggedinstatus === null || $pts === null)
        {
            die(json_encode(array("message" => "none")));
        }
        else
        {           
            return "more";
        }
    }

    function checkLoginCreds()
    {
        if(crypt($inPword, $password_hash) === $password_hash)
        {
            switch($loggedinstatus)
            {
                case  "no":         
                    $sel = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE login SET loggedin='yes' WHERE uname = ?");
                    $sel->execute(array($username));
                    return "AllGood";
                    break;

                defaut:
                    return "alreadyin";
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "BadLogin";
        }
    }

    if(getLoginInfo() === "more")
    {
        echo json_encode(array("message" => checkLoginCreds()));
    }

    getLoginInfo();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Finally, here's the output when I `var_dump()` the PDO connection.

`object(PDO)#1 (0) {}`

Comment: `$dbh` isn't defined in your function.

Comment: fixed the formatting @andrewsi

Comment: You should either define the whole thing in a class or connect to db in every function which requires db connection..

Comment: @copilot0910 - that still doesn't solve the problem. `$dbh` is out of scope - either pass it into the function as a parameter, or declare it as a global.

Comment: @blo I've seen the class approach yet don't know how do do it. Also, why does it not work in this file yet works in all the others?

Comment: Put the connection block in function and it will work..

Comment: Ok. The connection block fixes it. someone put it as an answer and i'll mark it correct. One question though. Why is there the scope error with the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, you need to use the global variable scope, explained here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

```
$mysql_user = "NotTelling";
$mysql_password = "DefinatelyNotThis";
try
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=somehost;dbname=somename", $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $inPword = $_POST['password'];
    $lat =  $_POST['lat'];
    $lon =  $_POST['lon'];

    $loggedin = "";
    $password_hash = "";
    $loggedinstatus = "";
    $pts = "";

    function getLoginInfo()
    {
        global $dbh, $username, $password_hash, $loggedinstatus, $pts;

        $sth = $dbh -> prepare('SELECT pword, loggedin, points FROM login WHERE uname = :uname');
        $sth->bindParam(':uname', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            echo $row['pword'];
            echo $row['loggedin'];
            echo $row['points'];
        }
        $password_hash = $fetch['pword'];
        $loggedinstatus = $fetch['loggedin'];
        $pts = $fetch["points"];

        if($password_hash === null || $loggedinstatus === null || $pts === null)
        {
            die(json_encode(array("message" => "none")));
        }
        else
        {           
            return "more";
        }
    }

    function checkLoginCreds()
    {
        global $dbh, $inPword, $password_hash, $loggedinstatus, $username;

        if(crypt($inPword, $password_hash) === $password_hash)
        {
            switch($loggedinstatus)
            {
                case  "no":         
                    $sel = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE login SET loggedin='yes' WHERE uname = ?");
                    $sel->execute(array($username));
                    return "AllGood";
                    break;

                defaut:
                    return "alreadyin";
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "BadLogin";
        }
    }

    if(getLoginInfo() === "more")
    {
        echo json_encode(array("message" => checkLoginCreds()));
    }

    getLoginInfo();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
}
```

But this can get messy very quickly.

I suggest you put the variables in an array or using OOP for a more robust solution: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can define it in a class..

```
class someClass {

  private $db;

  public function __construct(){


            $this->dbconnect();

    }

    private function dbconnect() {

      try { //try connection

        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=somenane', 'usernane', 'pass');

        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); 
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $this->dbh = $dbh;

      } catch (Exception $e) { //connection failed

        die("Oh no! It seems we took too long to respond");

      }

    }

    public function getLoginInfo() { 

      $sth = $this->dbh->prepare('SELECT pword, loggedin, points FROM login WHERE uname = :uname'); 
      $sth->bindParam(':uname', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR); 

      //cont the code

    }

}
```

Not sure if it's good enough..but it will work..

Comment: Connection in the every class is as bad as in every function.

Comment: @YourCommonSense If you have the "Correct" solution, why don't you just share it? Wait, you **DONT** because there are many ways to approach this.

Comment: All his function requires connection, what's the harm?

Comment: as well as all classes. which have to share a single connection, not create their own ones. which will result in as many connections as many objects they have.

Comment: @YourCommonSense can you edit or provide a link for a better way, I would like to learn it..

Comment: @blo ok so? Why doesn't he answer the question then? You could be terrible or amazing at coding, but if you just go around expecting everyone to understand everything like you do, you're an idiot. All I wanted was an answer, which you provided. He just posted a link. What use is that?

Comment: just make it  `function __construct($db){ $this->db = $db;}`  and then instantiate this class passing already created $db like this `$obj = new someClass($db);` this will make all objects to use single connection, instead of creating new ones (which will kill your db server pretty soon).

Comment: @YourCommonSense assuming that situation, what if I want to start a session but don't need a db connection?

Comment: okay, you can stick to your connect() function, but feed it with **already created connection** as well, instead of opening a new one. That is the point. I hope you got it at last.

Comment: only if your class is a dedicated DB handling class - only then you have to connect in it's method. I feel I have to make this note, just in case.

Comment: Yeah, what I actually use is, two class, one for main functions like getting request, starting sessions, and other extends for verifying values from db, which looks like this..