# PHP PDO Call to a member function execute() on a non object

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

So I'm using prepared statements to handle my JSON call from my cordova app to a database.

Right now, I'm trying to get nearby locations based on `POST`ed latitude and longitude, but the prepared statement isn't working.

When I set the variables to just test, I'm getting a `Call to a member function execute() on a non object` error.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong!

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $lat = 42.35674265310388;
    $lon = -71.13770473755070;
    $miles = 5;
    //$lat = $_POST["lat"];
    //$lon = $_POST["lon"];
    $data = array();

    $sth = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT *, (3959 * acos(cos(radians(?)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lon) - radians(?)) + sin(radians(?)) * sin(radians(lat)))) AS distance FROM members WHERE (3959 * acos(cos(radians(?)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lon) - radians(?)) + sin(radians(?)) * sin(radians(lat)))) < ? ORDER BY distance 5');
    $sth->execute(array($lat, $lon, $lat, $lat, $lon, $lat, $miles));
    $row = $sth->fetch();

    $data["markers"][] = array
    (
        "lat" => $row['lat'],
        "lon" => $row['lon']
    );

    print_r($data);

    echo json_encode($data);
```

Also, I `var_dump()`ed the `$lat` `$lon` and `$miles` variables, shown below.

```
lat - float(42.356742653104)
lon - float(-71.137704737551)
miles - int(5)
```

Comment: you've tagged this PDO yet you've called your database variable `$mysqli`? What do your database connection lines look like?

Comment: Quite funny to see this one after http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321504/php-select-with-pdo-call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-a-non-object-error

Comment: @YourCommonSense I changed everything. Also, novocaine88, I didn't change the variable name, but it is being called via PDO. Idk. Didn't change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sth = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT *, (3959 * acos(cos(radians(?)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lon) - radians(?)) + sin(radians(?)) * sin(radians(lat)))) AS distance FROM members WHERE (3959 * acos(cos(radians(?)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lon) - radians(?)) + sin(radians(?)) * sin(radians(lat)))) < ? ORDER BY distance 5');
```

There seems to be an error in the `query`, it fails on preparation before it is even executed due to `syntax validation` failure `ORDER BY distance 5` which is wrong.

It should be **either**

```
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

**OR**

```
ORDER BY distance DESC
```

Comment: @Downvoter: Can someone add a comment so that i can correct myself.

Comment: Also, when I `var_dump` the query, the response is `string(308)` followed by the query itself. Also, when I add the `bind_param` before executing, I get the same error, but the `execute()` becomes `bind_param()` I've seen it with the array in the `execute()` before, and has worked elsewhere in examples that weren't mine. Also, I have seen the `bind_param()` way you're saying.

Comment: Looks like he wants an order, and a limit...So ORDER ASC or ORDER DESC are fine, and add limit 5 after.

Comment: Fixing the `ORDER BY` has fixed it. Thanks!